# How do I use a form to add to an object?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object, append

I have a react javascript file which has an object with user data. I want to be able to use a form to add to that object by user typing in their name, food and age.

Literally just create another object item and add it to the array.

example : "export const objectName = [name: John, Food: pizza, Age: 22 ]"

I want to add a user from form input.

How would I do this in React? - I understand the basics of doing this in a Javascript file, but how would it specifically be done in React? - AS in how to I reference another file from a react component?

Comment: By looking for a basic tutorial...

Comment: `export const arrayName = [name: John, Food: pizza, Age: 22 ]`
You can't create an `array` like this. The format you are mentioning is the format for an `Object`. Please see the difference between `Object` and `Array` first.